# Cannot insert new values in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm trying to work on something. This is the code I've used from html to php. When i run it on the server and put values, it just refreshes the page. Is there something i need to change on the code

For connecting:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "1234";
$database = "finance_payments";

//connection error
$conn_error = "Could not connect.";

// Create connection
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);

$db_select = mysql_select_db($database);

 // Check connection and database selection
if(!mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password) || !mysql_select_db($database)){
 die($conn_error);
  }
?>
```

and for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Payments Register</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="Styles/registration_stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
//include/require the database connection file
require 'Includes/dbconnect.php';

//checking if fields are set
if(isset($_POST['S_No']) && isset($_POST['Date']) &&    isset($_POST['Payee']) && isset($_POST['Details']) && isset($_POST['Branch_or_Dept']) && isset($_POST['Amount']) && isset($_POST['Invoice_No'])){
    //creating variables
    $S_No = $_POST['S_No'];
    $Date = $_POST['Date'];
    $Payee = $_POST['Payee'];
    $Details = $_POST['Details'];
    $Branch_or_Dept = $_POST['Branch_or_Dept'];
    $Amount = $_POST['Amount'];
    $Inovice_No = $_POST['Invoice_No'];

    //checking if variables are not empty
    if(!empty($S_No) && !empty($Date) && !empty($Payee) &&   !empty($Details) && !empty($Branch_or_Dept) && !empty($Amount) && !empty($Inovice_No)){
        //if they are not empty

        //insert into database
        //to escape html injection - mysql_real_escape_string
        $query = "INSERT INTO payments_miscellaneous (S_No, Date, Payee, Details, Branch_or_Dept, Amount, Invoice_No) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($S_No)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($Date)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($Payee)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($Details)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($Branch_or_Dept)."','".mysql_real_escape_strin g($Amount)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($Inovice_No)."')";
        if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
            //direct to success page
            header('Location: finance_records/register_success.php');
        }else//if query fails{
            echo "Record not inserted, please try again later.";
        }

    }else{//if they are empty
        echo "All fields are required.";
    } 

?>

<header class="body">
  <h2><i><u>Payments Registration Form</u></i></h2>
</header>

<section class = "body">
<form method="post" action="miscellaneous.php">
    <label>S.No</label>
    <input name = "S_No" placeholder = "Enter number">
    <label>Date</label>
    <input name = "Date" placeholder = "Enter date">
    <label>Payee</label>
    <input name = "Payee" placeholder = "Enter name of payee">
    <label>Details</label>
    <input name = "Details" placeholder = "Enter details of payment">
    <label>Branch/Dept</label>
    <input name = "Branch_or_Dept" placeholder = "Enter branch/dept of   payee">
    <label>Amount</label>
    <input name = "Amount" placeholder = "Enter amount in ZMW or USD">
    <label>Invoice No</label>
    <input name = "Inovice_No" placeholder = "Enter invoice number">

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Enter">
</form>
```

```
         <p>
         <a HREF="index.php">Go back to homepage</a>
         </p>
```

Comment: have you changed your localhost password to 1234 ???
if you didn't change than make it blank . change $password = "" & start Using mysqli or PDO for security.

Comment: don't use mysql use mysqli.do you get any errors?

Comment: @Bhavin yes i changed the localhost password to 1234. When i try to leave it blank, the page does not load and i get an error.

Comment: @FastSnail No I'm not getting any errors. i tried using mysqli but i'm getting the same result.

Comment: @Rani8094 You can not get any error if you do not check for it

Comment: @Rani8094 use this function error_reporting(E_ALL); you will get all the errors. mysql_* APIs functions are deprecated now.

Comment: If INSERTION Not Happening, Then Are Your Getting This Message "*Record not inserted, please try again later*"??

Comment: its not the issue with mysql_connect or mysqli but, try to use mysqli. anyway i think you should check your insert query it may like ("insert into table_name(field1,field2) values ('$tblfield1','$tblfield2')");

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. It works, finally. The problem was that i had not closed the first If statement and had spelled invoice incorrectly. Lesson learnt.

Answer (score 0):

`date`is a [keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in mysql. so you have to escape the column Name:

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO payments_miscellaneous (S_No, `Date`, Payee, Details, Branch_or_Dept, Amount, Invoice_No) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($S_No)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($Date)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($Payee)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($Details)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($Branch_or_Dept)."','".mysql_real_escape_strin g($Amount)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($Inovice_No)."')";
```

Hint 1: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_´or`PDO` instead with prepared Statements to prevent SQL-injection.

Hint 2: Check for Errors after run SQL-command.

Comment: @Rani8094 Have you checked my answer?

Comment: yes i have. I've changed to mysqli_ . And when i click on enter, the values are not showing up in the DB and I am not getting the success or not successful message.

Comment: @Rani8094 Then this condition return false: `isset($_POST['S_No']) && isset($_POST['Date']) &&    isset($_POST['Payee']) && isset($_POST['Details']) && isset($_POST['Branch_or_Dept']) && isset($_POST['Amount']) && isset($_POST['Invoice_No'])
`

Answer (score 0):

Hi use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` as `mysql` is `depreciated`. Also print `mysqli error` if code not insert record in `database`. so add

```
print_r(mysqli_error($con)); in else part to `print error`
```

dbconnect.php

```
$con=mysqli_connect($servername ,$username,$password , $database);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

miscellaneous.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Payments Register</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="Styles/registration_stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>   

    <?php
    //include/require the database connection file
    require 'Includes/dbconnect.php';

    //checking if fields are set
    if(isset($_POST['S_No']) && isset($_POST['Date']) &&    isset($_POST['Payee']) && isset($_POST['Details']) && isset($_POST['Branch_or_Dept']) && isset($_POST['Amount']) && isset($_POST['Invoice_No'])){
        //creating variables
        $S_No = $_POST['S_No'];
        $Date = $_POST['Date'];
        $Payee = $_POST['Payee'];
        $Details = $_POST['Details'];
        $Branch_or_Dept = $_POST['Branch_or_Dept'];
        $Amount = $_POST['Amount'];
        $Inovice_No = $_POST['Invoice_No'];

        //checking if variables are not empty
        if(!empty($S_No) && !empty($Date) && !empty($Payee) &&   !empty($Details) && !empty($Branch_or_Dept) && !empty($Amount) && !empty($Inovice_No)){

            //to escape html injection - mysql_real_escape_string
            $query = "INSERT INTO payments_miscellaneous (S_No, Date, Payee, Details, Branch_or_Dept, Amount, Invoice_No) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($S_No)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($Date)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($Payee)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($Details)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($Branch_or_Dept)."','".mysql_real_escape_strin g($Amount)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($Inovice_No)."')";
           // echo $query;die; print it and see it is right
            if($query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query)){
                //direct to success page
                header('Location: finance_records/register_success.php');
            }else//if query fails{
                echo "Record not inserted, please try again later.";
                print_r(mysqli_error($con));// add this to print your sql error
            }

        }else{//if they are empty
            echo "All fields are required.";
        } 

    ?>

   // your form ...
```

Comment: What Changes You Did Man? Why This Answer Will Help OP? Explain Little Bit.